# Laravel - Faking a save failure in unit tests

Tags: laravel, phpunit

If we had the below code that we wanted to test, what would be the best way to simulate a failed save? At the moment the only part I am missing from my test is the `else` statement.

The save is part of a loop, where we take `$customers` loop through them and perform some actions.

```
$customers = Customer::where('created_at', '<=', $start);

$customers->each(function ($customer, $key) {
    if ($customer->save()) {
        //Do something here
    } else {
        //Saving failed, log something
    }
}
```

All the data for the tests come from factories, and are generated on the fly per test.

Comment: It depends what you're testing. Is the model injected via dependency injection or model binding or are you making it manually. In order to mock it you will need to be injecting it somehow. What are you testing? A controller or another class?

Comment: I've updated the question to include information about what $customer are and how they are loaded

Answer (score 1):

Well the easy but dirty thing to do is to fake a saving failiure through the `saving` event:

Here's the note from the event handler:

```
public function save(array $options = [])
{
    $query = $this->newModelQuery();

    // If the "saving" event returns false we'll bail out of the save and return
    // false, indicating that the save failed. This provides a chance for any
    // listeners to cancel save operations if validations fail or whatever.
    if ($this->fireModelEvent('saving') === false) {
        return false;
    }
   ....
```

Therefore something like the following should work:

```php
class TestModelSaving {
     public function testSaveFailureLogs() {
          // Create the fake model here
          // If the event handler for saving returns false then `save()` will return false
          Customer::saving(function () { return false; }); 
          // Call your unit under test here

          // Cleanup: Usually unnecessary, but some test configurations might need it
          Customer::flushEventListeners();

     }
}
```

In order to test if things are logged you could mock the logger facade via `Log::shouldReceive(....)` (parameters are the same for the mockery function with the same name)

Comment: Reading question and before scrolling to your answer, it came to my mind: maybe saved (instead saving) event would be appropriate in scenario?

Comment: @Tpojka  The way I read the question I thought this was about faking a save failure. Once the `saved` event is fired the save is already successful.

Comment: I considered other way around. In my mind it was "if saved is successful - test passed". I am not much experienced with tests though and try to learn though.